# Request SQL : users that follow each other

Tags: sql, inner-join, where-clause

Good morning,

I have structured my db this way :

[image]

[image]

And I'm struggling with my request. *How could I find users that follow each other ?*
I've tried this, in vain.

```
SELECT
    U1.id,
    U2.id
FROM
    USER U1,
    USER U2,
    FOLLOWS F1,
    FOLLOWS F2
WHERE
    F1.id_follower = U1.id
    AND F1.if_followed = U2.id
    AND F2.id_follower = U1.id
    AND F2.if_followed = U2.id
```

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Please tag your question with the specific database you are using

Comment: Please add some example data and expected results

Comment: `JOIN`.  `JOIN`.  `JOIN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want a self-join on `follows`:

```
select f1.id_follower as id1, f1.id_followed as id2
from follows f1
inner join follows f2 
    on  f2.id_follower = f1.id_followed
    and f2.id_followed = f1.id_follower
where f1.id_follower < f1.id_followed
```

This brings pairs of users which are following each other; each pair is displayed only once (the smallest id comes first).

If you need the corresponding users information, then that's two more joins:

```
select i1.id as id1, u1.name as name1, i1.id as id2, u2.name as name2
from follows f1
inner join follows f2 
    on  f2.id_follower = f1.id_followed
    and f2.id_followed = f1.id_follower
inner join users u1 
    on  u1.id = f1.id_follower
inner join users u2
    on  u2.id = f1.id_followed
where f1.id_follower < f1.id_followed
```

Answer (score 0):

select u.id, u.name from user u left join follows f on u.id=f.id_follower where f.id_follower in (select id_followed from follows);